# How to Export Datagridview to Excel Excluding invisible Rows?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, datagridview

Help me guys. this button code below allows me to export a filtered row values into excel.

I added a radio button that makes some rows invisible
when i press my export button(code below), it also export my invisible rows.
I wanted to add an if statement to check if row.visible = false then skips it from exporting

I'm new to Coding so please help me

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xlapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim xlworkbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlworksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misvalue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    xlapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(misvalue)
    xlworksheet = xlworkbook.Sheets("sheet1")


    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                xlworksheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                xlworksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value
            Next
        Next
    Next

    xlworksheet.SaveAs("E:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    xlworkbook.Close()
    xlapp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlapp)
    releaseObject(xlworkbook)
    releaseObject(xlworksheet)

    MsgBox("You can find the file E:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    Dim res As MsgBoxResult
    res = MsgBox("Process completed, Would you like to open the file?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If (res = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
        Process.Start("E:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The outer loop for i=o iterates through the rows, so I would add your If statement immediately below that. You want the If to pass if it finds a visible row, so something like If (DataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible) { ...

Comment: i already did that before posting here. it gives me a blank excel file. just wondering what went wrong with if statement code.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the row to see if it is visible or not. If it's visible then process else skip it.

```
 For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        If DataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = True Then ' If the row is visible then iterate through the columns/cells
           For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                  xlworksheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                  xlworksheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value
                 Next
           Next
         End If

Next
```

Comment: This would also make ALL the rows visible because you are assigning True to their Visible properties. Try using == in expressions when comparing values. In this case it is not necessary to compare Visible with anything, since it is already Boolean. If (DataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible) would do it.

Comment: Hi there. 

i tried using your code and it give me an error. changing [i] to (i) solves the error but it gives me a blank excel file when exporting..

Comment: Not in Visual Basic, I know it sounds stupid (I come from a c# background) but If x=True actually translates to if(x==true).

Comment: Yeah, I work in it at my job and it took me a while to stop trying c# intermixed with it. As far as using Excel Interop, that's a hairy beast. I seem to recall it's not as easy as just setting to Cells(x,y) to certain values.

Comment: maybe something is missing? or should i incorporate my populate button(button that makes row invisible) into my export button?

Comment: I would put a breakpoint on the If statement and check the Visible property of the rows in the data grid there. Maybe they are not set how we think they are. The code should work, really.

Answer (score 0):

Good day Guys. i finally resolve my problem and it skips the invisible rows

the prob is. when exporting. it leave a blank row when datagridview.row = invisible

here is the code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xlapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim misvalue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim rowsTotal, colsTotal As Short
    Dim V, I, J As Short
    xlapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application


    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor

    Dim excelBook As Excel.Workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add
    Dim excelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(excelBook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    xlapp.Visible = True
    rowsTotal = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    colsTotal = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1

    With excelWorksheet
        .Cells.Select()
        .Cells.Delete()
        Dim curCol As Short = 0
        For iC = 0 To colsTotal
            If DataGridView1.Columns(iC).Visible Then
                .Cells(1, curCol + 1).Value = DataGridView1.Columns(iC).HeaderText
                curCol += 1
            End If

        Next

        For I = 0 To rowsTotal
            curCol = 0
            For J = 0 To colsTotal
                DataGridView1.Rows(I).Visible = True
                .Cells(I + 2, curCol + 1).value = DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(J).Value
                curCol += 1
            Next J

        Next I

        .Rows("1:1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Rows("1:1").Font.Size = 10
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit()
        .Cells.Select()
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
        .Cells(1, 1).Select()


        excelWorksheet.SaveAs("E:\vbexcel.xlsx")
        xlapp.Quit()
        xlapp.Quit()

        releaseObject(xlapp)
        releaseObject(excelBook)
        releaseObject(excelWorksheet)

    End With

    MsgBox("You can find the file E:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    Dim res As MsgBoxResult
    res = MsgBox("Process completed, Would you like to open the file?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
    If (res = MsgBoxResult.Yes) Then
        Process.Start("E:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    End If

End Sub
```

Is there a way i can use a macro that deletes blank row inside this  code?